# verifying zipcode? do i need regex?

Tags: java, regex

I need to verify that String zip is 5 numbers long and starts with 80, 81, 82, or 83.
do I need a regex to do this?

I have tried `boolean validZip = (zip.length() == 5 && zip.charAt(0) == 8 && zip.charAt(1) >= 0 && zip.charAt(1) <= 3);` but 80221 returns false for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
boolean validZip = (zip.length() == 5 && zip.charAt(0) == '8' && zip.charAt(1) >= '0' && zip.charAt(1) <= '3');
```

You were comparing ASCII values. To compare characters, you need to write them in single quote. If you want to compare ASCII values, then it can be done as following:

```
boolean validZip = (zip.length() == 5 && zip.charAt(0) == 56 && zip.charAt(1) >= 48 && zip.charAt(1) <= 51);
```

ASCII values for 0-9 ranges from 48-57.

Comment: Your answer also fixed what I initially had in my code!

Comment: Actually, charAt returns the [UTF-16 code unit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) value. That the UTF-16 code unit is a complete Unicode codepoint that is also an ASCII codepoint that represents the same character is not relevant to the method.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/BYH6yH/1)

```
^8[0123]\d{3}$
```

And use it in java like this

```
String zipcode = "80882";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^8[0123]\\d{3}$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(zipcode);
boolean validZip = m.find();
```